# Working with current date in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

I am working with current date in sqlitedatabase.

```
 public String getDataforSevenDays() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};

            String result =" ";


        long sevenDays = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, KEY_DATE +  " > "+ sevenDays, null, null, null, null);

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

                result = result + c.getString(iName) + "\n";     

            }

            return result;

          }
```

Now if I wanted to query database and get data for the last 14 days, would this be the right way to do it?

```
long fourteenDays = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, KEY_DATE +  " > "+ fourteenDays, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Depends really on how you are storing the dates in the database.

Comment: I am storing it as cv.put(KEY_DATE, sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));    So if I want to query the database for last 14 days, would I write the query like this long fourteenDays = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;

Comment: If you're using millisecond integers in your queries, use millisecond integers and not formatted strings when storing as well.

Comment: How can i store date as millisecond, please give an example. Thanks

Comment: `cv.put(KEY_DATE, System.currentTimeInMillis());`

Answer (score 0):

Queries like that work, provided that you're also storing millisecond timestamps in the database.

Based on the comments, you're storing formatted date strings so the queries won't work. To fix that, store instead the long integer values such as returned by `System.getTimeInMIllis()` or `Date` `getTime()`.

Also if you calculate slightly longer time periods, use longs in the calculation to prevent 32-bit signed integer overflow, e.g. change `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14` to `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14L`.

Comment: I am sorry here, may be I am not understanding. I am storing the date in the database as SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
              
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_DATE, sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))); Would this be considered as date string or a long integer value when storing.Thanks a bunch